# How to clean this webscrape up

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape a table from a webpage, but there are two tables with the same tag.

The table I am interested in is "Event Timeline."

My problem is my code prints my desired table as a whole, and does not separate by column/row.

Ideally I would want this to be broken up per field.

Is there a way to clean this scrape up

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
import pandas as pd
val=[]

driver.get('https://www.aan.com/MSA/Public/Events/Details/13419')
page_source = driver.page_source
element2=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody').text.strip()
print(element2)
```

Comment: You could also probably try df=pd.read_html(element2) . Import pandas as pd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium's purpose is more on web automation, therefore I will answer your question using a web scraping package `BeautifulSoup` instead.

This answer obtain the page's HTML file using your code, but a more efficient solution will be the `Request` package.

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import time
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
val = []

# Suggest using the Request package to obtain the HTML source code
driver.get('https://www.aan.com/MSA/Public/Events/Details/13419')
page_source = driver.page_source
# element2 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')

# Declare a BeautifulSoup Object
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
tbody = soup.find("tbody")                                 #Find the first tbody
rows = tbody.find_all("tr")                                #Find all the rows
for row in rows:
    rowVal = []                                            #Create an array to store the value
    tds = row.find_all("td")                               #Find all the cells in the row
    for td in tds:
        rowVal.append(td.get_text().strip())               #Obtain text of the cell
    print(rowVal)                                          #Print them, or do anything else
```

Comment: Thanks, this prints great. What would be the best way to put this answer in a DataFrame/Excel? I tried to import pandas, and then do df=pd.DataFrame(rowVal) but that didnt seem to do anything for me

Comment: I added to dictionary and did some formatting. It seemed to do the trick... thank you again :)